# Foreign characters broken in Excel, is there a way to import file from Notepad++ with working characters?

Tags: xml, excel, csv, notepad++

I'm not sure how to title my problem the best way, but I have a file (from a WordPress plugin) that I can download as a CSV or XML. It contains foreign characters ([Latin Extended-A apparently](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_Extended-A)) that appear as broken characters in Excel 2010 (CSV). Opening the XML file in Excel doesn't work because *the specified XML source does not refer to a schema*.

However, the CSV opens with the correct characters in Notepad++. The data is confusing because it isn't neatly displayed like excel. I found a plugin (TextFX) that'll sort out all my columns to display neatly. Is there a way I can save the file in Notepad++ and export it into Excel and have the special characters saved and working? Or is there a another workaround to getting either the CSV or XML file working correctly in Excel?

Answer (score 1):

You may be double-clicking the CSV from an Explorer folder window and expecting it to open in Excel properly. You need to use the Data ► Get External Data ► From Text command.

Once the first stage of the Text Import Wizard opens, you will be able to choose a code page that matches the desired character set.

[image: Text Import Wizard Character Set]

The Text Import Wizard's actions are recordable.

For more automation, you can also explore the avenues within the [Workbooks.OpenText method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837097.aspx) and its optional *Origin* parameter for setting a code page.

Comment: Okay, so changed it to UTF-8 allows me to see my characters clearly, but it opens up as one long row, separataed by commas. Is there a way to have it open up like it normally would in Excel, one item per cell?

Comment: It sounds like you chose **Fixed Width** or those are not commas but some sort of UTF-8 equivalent. However, I'm just throwing mud at a wall without being able to see the original CSV file. Consider posting a redacted portion it to a public file repository.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped. Would you mind walking me through how to post a redacted portion to a file depository? I have never done that before.

Comment: If you are new at publishing a file for public access, then Google-Droive or https://www.dropbox.com/ would be your best bet. Each have numerous tutorials on how to get a file published. You could also send the file to me at the email address on [this page](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/profile/a05bdd23-6c19-4f50-9b4a-3c6ae7d72590?sort=lastreplydate&dir=desc&tab=qna&forum=&filter=All&page=1&tm=1374165688591&auth=1#user-profile-tab-profile).

Comment: Thanks, I emailed you.

Comment: Did you receive my email?